# JPA(Hibernate) UPDATE problem using JpaRepository.save() method in Mapping Relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity, hibernate-onetomany

**Floor.java**

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "floors")
@Builder
public class Floor {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "floor_id", nullable = false)
    private String floorId;
    @Column(name = "floor_name", nullable = false)
    private String floorName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "building_id", nullable = true)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Building building;

    @Column(name = "floor_order", nullable = false)
    private int floorOrder;
    @Column(name = "floor_image_url", nullable = true)
    private int floorImageUrl;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "floor", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE }, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Seat> seats;
}
```

**Seat.java**

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "seats")
public class Seat {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "seat_id", nullable = false)
    private String seatId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "floor_id", nullable = false) // owner of the relationship
    @JsonBackReference
    private Floor floor;
    @Column(name = "x", nullable = false)
    private double x;
    @Column(name = "y", nullable = false)
    private double y;
    @Column(name = "is_group", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isGroup;

    @Column(name = "group_id", nullable = true)
    private String groupId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") // owner of the relationship
    @JsonBackReference
    private Employee employee;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "figure_id", nullable = false)
    private Figure figure;
}
```

**FloorController.java(Code being modified)**

```java
package com.hancom.hanzari.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.hancom.hanzari.dto.FloorDto;
import com.hancom.hanzari.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.hancom.hanzari.model.Building;
import com.hancom.hanzari.model.Floor;
import com.hancom.hanzari.service.BuildingService;
import com.hancom.hanzari.service.FloorService;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/buildings/{building_id}/floors")
public class FloorController {

    @Autowired
    private FloorService floorService;
    @Autowired
    private BuildingService buildingService;

    @Transactional
    @GetMapping(produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<List<FloorDto>> getAllFloorsInBuilding(@PathVariable("building_id") String buildingId)
            throws Exception {
        Building building = buildingService.findById(buildingId);
        if (building == null) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Building", "building_id", buildingId);
        }
        List<Floor> floor = floorService.findByBuilding(building);
        List<FloorDto> result = new ArrayList<FloorDto>();
        floor.forEach(e -> result.add(e.toDto()));
        return new ResponseEntity<List<FloorDto>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Transactional
    @GetMapping(value = "/{floor_id}", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<FloorDto> getFloor(@PathVariable("building_id") String buildingId,
            @PathVariable("floor_id") String floorId) throws Exception {
        Building building = buildingService.findById(buildingId);
        if (building == null) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Building", "building_id", buildingId);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<FloorDto>(floorService.findById(floorId).toDto(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Floor> save(@PathVariable("building_id") String buildingId, @RequestBody FloorDto floorDto)
            throws Exception {
        /*
         * for (Field field : floorDto.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
         * field.setAccessible(true); Object value = field.get(floorDto);
         * System.out.println(field.getName() + " : " + value + " // type : " +
         * value.getClass()); }
         */

        Building building = buildingService.findById(buildingId);
        if (building == null) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Building", "building_id", buildingId);
        }
        /*Floor newFloor = Floor.builder().floorId(floorDto.getFloor_id()).floorName(floorDto.getFloor_name())
                .building(building).floorOrder(floorDto.getFloor_order()).build();*/
        
        
        
        Floor newFloor = new Floor();
        newFloor.setFloorId(floorDto.getFloor_id());
        newFloor.setFloorName(floorDto.getFloor_name());
        newFloor.setFloorOrder(floorDto.getFloor_order());
        newFloor.setBuilding(building);
        //newFloor.setSeats(new ArrayList<Seat>());
        
        if(newFloor.getSeats() == null) {
            System.out.println("#####\n#####\nseats null#####\n#####\n");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("#####\n#####\nseats not null#####\n#####\n");
        }
        
        floorService.save(newFloor);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<Floor>(newFloor, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{floor_id}", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteFloorById(@PathVariable("floor_id") String floor_id) {
        System.out.println("==================================================================");
        System.out.println("seatId: " + floor_id);
        System.out.println("==================================================================");

        floorService.deleteById(floor_id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

`Floor` and `Seat` have a bidirectional relationship owned by `Floor`.

The problem occurs when calling `FloorController.save()` for the `floor`.
[FloorController.save()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGcSw.png)

When I first `save()` a `Floor` object, it works correctly.
[SUCCESS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj2wp.png)

But I want to be able to edit the already saved `Floor`, so in order to modify the information of an existing object, it fails if the value to be modified (modify "floor_name") is delivered in the form of Dto including the floor_id of the existing object.
[FAIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtDaz.png)

The error that occurs is:

```
2020-10-27 14:32:59.436 ERROR 10508 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemExce
ption: org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.hancom.hanzari.model.Floor.seats; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: A col
lection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.hancom.hanzari.model.Floor.seats] with root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.hancom.hanzari.model.Floor.seats
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processDereferencedCollection(Collections.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processUnreachableCollection(Collections.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.lambda$flushCollections$1(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.forEachCollectionEntry(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1136) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushCollections(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1363) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:454) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3213) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2381) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:633) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

As a result of searching for the related error, I found that it was an error that was caused by Hibernate not managing the `List<Seat> seats` referenced in the `Floor`.

Comment: Can you include the code of the method where you call `FloorController.save()`

Comment: "I keep trying, but there is no progress, so I ask again in a few days." Please don't. This would be considered spamming.

Comment: "and is the owner of the relationship through @JoinColumn." `@JoinColumn` doesn't make an attribute owner of a relationship. The `mappedBy` on the non-owning side does that.

Comment: Please post your actual code, not a prose description of it nor images.

Comment: First of all, thank you for commenting. Sir. 
I added the code as you said. check please .
@JensSchauder